# Format the design of the table exported to excel using display tag

Tags: java, css, excel, jsp, displaytag

Is it possible to design the look of table that is exported to excel using display tag
        (as like in jxl) i couldn't find any information regarding this topic.Does anyone has any ideas?

```
      <display:table id="data" name="sessionScope.UserForm.actorList" requestURI="/userAction.do" pagesize="10" export="true" >
        <display:column property="tvShow" title="TV Show" sortable="true"   />
        <display:column property="userName" title="User Name" sortable="true"  />
        <display:column property="emailId" title="Email Id" sortable="true"  />
        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="Details.xls"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="Details.pdf"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
     </display:table>
```

Comment: Let me know what kind of format that you are looking? Are you looking for custom background colour, even odd colours?

Comment: @Raghavendra Reddy Busireddy thanks for the reply,i need the exported table look as like in the jsp page withe same font,background color

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure my answer can suit your case. you can define your own exporting class. you can define that class by extending current excel export class. perhaps your goal can be achieved a little modification on that new class.